# How long should a person wait for an interview call after applying to a post?

Tags: resume, job-search, job-change

How long should a person wait for an interview call after applying to a post? I am not applying to other companies because I am happy where I am. Recently, however, I saw an even better opportunity and applied to that job. It's in a different technology so I take time out of my weekends to prepare for the interview. It's been one week since I applied to that job. I was wondering: how long should I wait for the interview and keep on preparing?

Comment: Take a look at [how long should you wait to move on when you haven’t heard back from an employer?](http://www.askamanager.org/2012/07/how-long-should-you-wait-to-move-on-when-you-havent-heard-back-from-an-employer.html) The answer there is straightforward: don't wait. _Move on immediately._ If you're preparing for an interview that you haven't been invited to yet, then you're probably overestimating your importance/abilities. But you won't be wasting your time since you're probably learning something new.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How long it takes for companies to set up interviews varies dramatically from company to company. Some employers do interviews on a rolling basis, as strong applications come in. Others have a set application period of, say, three to four weeks possibly and don’t contact anyone until that period is over. And others are just really slow — they should be contacting people within a few weeks but because of disorganization, inefficiency, and so forth don’t contact candidates for months. If you want to follow up in some way, send a polite email reiterating your strong interest in the job and saying that you’d love to talk when they’re ready to begin scheduling interviews.

Comment: I dont want to send anymore emails as I think I have sent a lot of emails already.I applied on their global website.Then I sent my CV to their local job hiring email.Then I sent my CV to their HR.

Comment: More than once, I've had companies take more than 6 months to contact me.  In one case, it resulted in a job.

Comment: @zzzzz, here's another one you may find helpful: [my mother says I should call employers daily for an interview](http://www.askamanager.org/2013/03/my-mother-says-i-should-call-employers-daily-for-an-interview.html)

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, companies that are serious about hiring will get back to you fairly quickly.  I've had employers contact me almost immediately after sending my resume (minutes/hours), though usually it's at least a couple of days.  Anything more than 2 weeks and I'd usually assume I wasn't going to get a call.

That said, I've had companies (usually the big ones) contact me a couple of months after I'd already interviewed for and started a new job somewhere else wanting to set up an interview.  While that's irritating, if I had still been unemployed, I probably would have accepted the interview.

I wouldn't stop applying and sending out resumes until you've accepted a job offer... worst case you end up with a week or two of back-to-back job interviews.  Maybe even multiple offers.

Answer (score 2):

In the software and tech business, no more than a week.  I've been hired at the close of the interview five or six times.  I've been in a few situations where I faxed a resume at 10:00 in the morning, interviewed at 2:00 in the afternoon, and gotten my offer at 4:00 PM.  Companies that take 'weeks' to respond to developer and network tech resumes are 'out of the running' a lot of the time - qualified candidates will already been in their new job by the time a slow employer decides to schedule an interview.

The 'unusual' circumstances might include something with heavy background checking, one's first attempt in a management role, or a 'long shot' migration to a new technology.  However, you should hear something: a hint that they're interested and plan to talk to you within a particular timeframe.